# The sketch freezes after couple of http request

Tags: http, arduino, esp8266

I have simple sketch on ESP8266 that send http request to the server.It works fine for one or two request and then it just hangs/freeze.It just stops looping but no errors at all.The board itself works fine if i comment out the `check connection` function. It has to be something i am not doing right in check connection maybe?Here is my code .Any help will be appreciated.Thank you in advance.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#define SSID      "xxxxxxxx"
#define PASS_SSID "xxxxxxxx"

WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("debugger");

  checkConnection();
    String string;
    while (client.available()) {
        string.concat((char)client.read());
        delay(1000);
    }
     Serial.println(string);
}

void checkConnection() {
    if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        WiFi.begin(SSID, PASS_SSID);
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
            Serial.print(".");
            delay(1000);
        }
    }
    if (!client.connected()) {
        if (client.connect("myapp.herokuapp.com", 80)) {
            Serial.println("connected to client");
            client.println("GET /api/users?data=25 HTTP/1.1");
            client.println("Host: myapp.herokuapp.com");
            client.println("Accept: */*");
            client.println();
            delay(1000);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was messing everything up.After taking it out everything works fine.

```
   String string;
   while (client.available()) {
    string.concat((char)client.read());
   delay(1000);
}
 Serial.println(string);
```